# jQuery UI Datepicker - how to always display it at top: 240px?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I've got datepicker assigned to date range selectors in my graph.
Is there some simple way to trigger action when the datepicker is displayed?
I would like to do the following every time it opens:

```
$("#ui-datepicker-div").css("top","240px");
```

there is beforeShow, but no afterShow. If I set the CSS in my page, it switches dynamically after displaying the datepicker, so that is a no go.

Comment: Why not set in your stylesheet: `#ui-datepicker-div { top: 240px !important; }` ?

Comment: @urbz !important did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

There was a [topic](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/datepicker-after-show-event) opened on jQuery forum with the same question.

So, as shown in that topic, you can use an refactored datepicker which can be downloaded from https://github.com/kbwood/jquery-ui .

This datepicker is providing the method `onShow` which, I think, fulfills your requirements.

You may try to replace the datepicker.js file with this one https://github.com/kbwood/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js

Answer (score 0):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/fzg5wsyd/)

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();    
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there was a bug raised for this too in **[THIS LINK](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6885)** where in there's a suggestion to do as below:

> if you need a "afterShow"-event befor version 1.9 you can overwrite
>   the datepicker._updateDatepicker fuction.
>
> for example:
>
> ```
> $(function() {
>   $.datepicker._updateDatepicker_original = $.datepicker._updateDatepicker;
>   $.datepicker._updateDatepicker = function(inst) {
>       $.datepicker._updateDatepicker_original(inst);
>       var afterShow = this._get(inst, 'afterShow');
>       if (afterShow)
>           afterShow.apply((inst.input ? inst.input[0] : null));  // trigger custom callback
>   }
> });
> ```
>
> I know it isn't the best way to slove this problem, but it's better
>   than change the original jquery-ui code.